# How to lock a group of images in Microsoft Word 2007?

Tags: microsoft-word

I am making a chart for my grandson. I have designed a stop light; a text box with three round images (sometimes colored) to form the stop light.

I should be able to lock the images so that the entire stop light can be copied, moved or whatever.

So, how can I lock the design?

I am using Word 2007 on Windows 7.

Comment: Please clarify the version of Word your using.  I believe you mean `Word 2007` which isn't `Word 7.0` which was released **20 years ago** in 1995 and would not even be able to run on Windows 7 for that reason.

Answer (score 2):

Insert > Shapes > New Drawing Canvas. Resize the canvas to an appropriate size.

You then have to cut (CTRL-X) and paste (CTRL-V) the individual images INTO the canvas. Thereafter, you can cut/copy/move the entire canvas as one single entity.

Answer (score 1):

The only way you can treat 3 separate images as one is by taking a screenshot using [snipping tool](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/snipping-tool-faq) or any other similar tool

Comment: Decent workaround.